# Update scrollbar in success of ajax

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar

I am using Ace_admin template and my side bar is dynamically generated.
I want to update scrollbar when new li are loaded into sidebar

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("testMethod")',
    dataType: "json",
    mtype: "post",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#sidebar").ace_scroll({ inline_style: true, size: 680, observeContent: true });
    }
});
```

But it does not update after adding new `li` to sidebar..